# Can't get date show in ActiveGantt CSN timeblocks

Tags: c#, winforms, gantt-chart

(As you can see in the provided image, the timeblocks are empty.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnIqf.png

(Expected Result)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcoYo.jpg

Hello everybody.
So I tried to replicate the the sample CarRental I'm succesfull at importing events from the database but I can't show no other than TimeMarkArea.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: improve your question

Comment: So I want to be able to display year, month and days in the timeline exactly like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/KcoYo.jpg. But even copying the code it doesn't work. I understood that I needed to use timeblocks but still can achieve to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting this question. First and foremost the terminology you are using is wrong. You are referring to TimeLine Tiers and not TimeBlocks.

Here's an image that shows the difference between the two:

[image: difference between TimeLine tiers and TimeBlocks in the ActiveGantt Scheduler Component]

You have not posted any code, but as this is a very common issue, I can imagine that the problem is that when you copied the code you did not override:

```
    private void ActiveGanttCSNCtl1_CustomTierDraw(object sender, AGCSN.CustomTierDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Interval == E_INTERVAL.IL_HOUR & e.Factor == 12)
        {
            e.Text = e.StartDate.ToString("tt").ToUpper();
        }
        if (e.Interval == E_INTERVAL.IL_MONTH & e.Factor == 1)
        {
            e.Text = e.StartDate.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
        }
        if (e.Interval == E_INTERVAL.IL_DAY & e.Factor == 1)
        {
            e.Text = e.StartDate.ToString("ddd d");
        }
    }
```

If you look at the load event for the form, when you are adding the view:

oView = ActiveGanttCSNCtl1.Views.Add(E_INTERVAL.IL_MINUTE, 30, E_TIERTYPE.ST_CUSTOM, E_TIERTYPE.ST_CUSTOM, E_TIERTYPE.ST_CUSTOM);

The Tier types are all set to custom. This is the documentation for the Add Method.

http://www.sourcecodestore.com/Documentation/Topic.aspx?PN=AG&PL=CSN&LID=1453

And this is the documentation for the CustomTierDraw event:

http://www.sourcecodestore.com/Documentation/Topic.aspx?PN=AG&PL=CSN&LID=274

If the TierType is set to E_TIERTYPE.ST_CUSTOM the control will invoke the CustomTierDraw event when drawing captions for the Tier object. If the CustomTierDraw is not overridden then the tiers will have no caption and they will show up as blank.

Best Regards,

Julio Luzardo

http://www.sourcecodestore.com

Comment: Spot on ! You find exactly what was wrong, great job.Thank you very much for your support. Quality work from you and http://www.sourcecodestore.com have a nice day .

Comment: thank you. Feel free to post as many questions as you need here on stackoverflow, will gladly help you out.